# Sympy extend() method losing element attributes

Tags: python, matplotlib, sympy

I have run into a problem with the Sympy plotting function where a plot loses attributes when extended off another plot.

```
x = Symbol('x')
p1 = plot(x, show=False)
p2 = plot(2*x, show=False)
p1.label = 'Line'
print(p1.label) #Prints: Line
p2.extend(p1)
print(p2[1].label) #Prints: x
```

I would like to set attributes for a given line then use the `.extend()` to place it on to another plot. Is there a workaround/better method for this action in `sympy.plotting`? The `.append()` method has the same issue.